# Vue.js How to define (override) css style in a Component?

Tags: vue.js, components

The default style for the **p** tag on my page has some bottom margin. My component uses **p** tags, and accordingly, the **p** tags in my component text show the corresponding bottom margin. How can I override/define new css style for the **p** tags in my component. I define my component like this:

```
 Vue.component ('activity-component', {

  props: {

            customer_id:{},
            is_admin:{},         
            isAdmin:{},      
            isKitsActionplan:{},
            ....

    template:
      `<div 
            class="row msDashboard-box"
            style="cursor:default;padding-top:12px; 
                    padding-bottom:12px;"
            >
        ... 
        <p> ... </p>
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try this approach,
Pass a variable with the class name to the component

```
<my-component v-bind:class="variable with class name"></my-component>
```

Then apply a rule to all p elements inside it, something like this i guess:

```
    .test p{
      your styles
    }
```

U can see more here: [vue api class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

I dont know for sure if this was what you wanted, but i gave it a shot :)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You have several options - choose your own adventure:

**Use a global utility style**

Somewhere globally, define a utility class like:

```css
.u-margin-reset {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Then in your template:

```html
<p class="u-margin-reset">hello</p>
```

---

**Use scoped CSS**

If you are using [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), you can use [scoped css](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html):

```
<template>
  <p class="special-p">hello</p>
</template>

<style scoped>
.special-p {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

---

**Use inline styles**

```js
Vue.component('activity-component', {
  template: `<p style="margin:0;"></p>`,
});
```

or

```js
Vue.component('activity-component', {
  computed: {
    myStyle() {
      return {
        margin: 0,
      };
    },
  },
  template: `<p :style="myStyle"></p>`,
});
```

---

> As an aside, I'd recommend using a CSS reset that globally resets the margins of all elements to 0. Then each component should set the margins as needed for its child elements/components. This may not be reasonable if you already have a large codebase, however.

Comment: Thanks David for your detailed inputs. Unfortunately, I can't add a class to the p tags inside my component as these are dynamically generated by an editor. However, I will try to programmatically change the p tags in watch -- hopefully this will work. Currently, I have used a workaround -- I have put all those p tags inside a div and used CSS to to change the p tags inside that div