# Add .bulma-class to all buttons in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bulma

This sounds simple, but actually I am struggling: How can I add a bulma-class to e.g. all buttons in Vue.js. Something like:

```
App.vue:

<template>[...]</template>
<script>[...]</script>
<style>
button {
  .button /*add bulma class .button to all buttons*/
  .is-danger /*add bulma class .is-danger to all buttons*/
  .m-5 /*add bulma class .m-5 to all buttons*/
}
</style>
```

Or is this just possible to store it in data an apply it with :class (kind of ugly, no?).

Right now I have to do this to each button, but this does not feel right:

```
<button class="button is-danger m-3" @click="myfunction">
  mybutton
</button>
```

I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks

Comment: I feel like this thread is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498003/vue-js-how-to-define-override-css-style-in-a-component

Comment: could we do `button{.button .is-danger}`  in bulma? if yes what's the name of this pattern?

Comment: Nah, that's the question. My code is not working, it just explains what I am trying to to (combine several bulma classes and apply them with basic css-selectors).

Comment: You could add classes using pure js code